# Runtime error in fusioncharts.js file while browsing report page in IE 11

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, fusioncharts

I am using Fusionchart Version 2.0 for report creation in my Asp.net project.
But I am getting javascript runtime syntax error in `FusionCharts.js` file on line

```
e = (new window.DOMParser).parseFromString(b,"text/xml")
```

When I run my aspx report page in `IE 11`. This report works fine in Google Chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

FusionCharts v2.0 is an older version. Can you try using the latest version of FusionCharts?

Download link:http://www.fusioncharts.com/download/